# Why is the .ctor() created when I compile C# code into IL?

Tags: c#, il, csc, ildasm

With this simple C# code, I run `csc hello.cs; ildasm /out=hello.txt hello.exe`.

```
class Hello
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}
```

This is the IL code from ildasm.

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Hello
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       13 (0xd)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "hi"
    IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b:  nop
    IL_000c:  ret
  } // end of method Hello::Main

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // Code size       7 (0x7)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  ret
  } // end of method Hello::.ctor

} // end of class Hello
```

What's the use of `.method public instance void  .ctor()` code? It doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's the default parameterless constructor. You're correct; it doesn't do anything (besides passing on to the base `Object()` constructor, which itself doesn't do anything special either anyway).

The compiler always creates a default constructor for a non-static class if there isn't any other constructor defined. Any member variables are then initialized to defaults. This is so you can do

```
new Hello();
```

without running into errors.

Comment: More on default constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx

Comment: This also means that the asker can get rid of it by making his class static: `static class Hello { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

This is covered in section 10.11.4 of the C# language spec

> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided. That default constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct base class

Here `Hello` has no defined constructor hence the compiler inserts the default do nothing constructor which just calls the base / object version

Answer (score 2):

A class for which you don't define a constructor gets an implicit public default constructor.

```
public MyClass()
  :base()
{
}
```

This only works if the base class has an accessible parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

class Hello inherits object, the default generated constructor simply calls the constructor of class `object`.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the specification stipulates that since your class itself is not static or abstract, it must expose a default parameterless constructor. This way, other users of whatever library or PE you build can instantiate a copy of your class.

If it didn't have a .ctor, it could be construed as having a private .ctor, I suppose. It's generally pretty vague. But logically, you're right, there is no need for the .ctor in this instance.